# How do I use the font if it does exist in CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts

I want to use some Google fonts but I know that some countries block any Google elements (I tried to log into some websites used fonts from Google in some overseas countries where Google had been spammed which caused that the websites were loaded slowly and finally the browser said the website could not be accessed)

So my question is, how I can use the font if `<link href="sth.google.com" ...\>` in `<head\>` was functional but if user tried to visit my website from some countries I mentioned they can choose to "disabled" that link (probably the visitors click some buttons on my website before they got to my homepage then the `<link \>` could be commented out automatically and use the default font to display the elements on my sites).

Comment: If you have the font file you can use SIFR.
http://www.sifrgenerator.com/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web Font Loader gives you added control when using linked fonts via @font-face. It provides a common interface to loading fonts regardless of the source, then adds a standard set of events you may use to control the loading experience

https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader#timeouts

in this case don't use webfont.js google cdn :) use your own

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.5.10/webfont.js"></script>
<script>

//this block is non necessary if you want to   
//override default timeout use this #####################
    WebFontConfig = {
        google: {
            families: ['Lobster','Droid Serif']
        },
        timeout: 5000 // Set the timeout to two seconds
    };
//########################################################

    WebFont.load({
        google: {
            families: ['Lobster', 'Droid Serif']
        }
    });
</script>

<p style="font-family:'Lobster'; font-size: 60px">asdasdasd</p>
<p style="font-size: 60px">asdasdasd</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download the fonts from Google into a font folder that you'll put in the .root of your site and then link directly to the fonts in that folder. You can also put a comma after that font and specify a default font, eg:
 font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;